# RegEx for Both Integer & Float

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a **RegEx** to match both **Integer** values as well as **Float** numbers.
and i want to use it using **Regular Expression Validator **

#### What should be **Valid**:

```
.1

.12

1.2

1.23

12.3

12.34

1

12
```

#### What should be **Invalid**:

```
.123(this value is having more then 2 decimal values)

1.234(this value is having more then 2 decimal values)
```

What i exactly want is to take values from 0 to 99.99 only in TextBox(**MaxLength=5**) Control in ASP.Net with C#.

Comment: What did you come up with so far? Post your attempt so we can see what you are having trouble with.

Comment: which language u r using with regex??`perl`,`php`,`java`???

Comment: I tried this expression (\d\d?\.\d\d?)|([0-9])
but im not able to enter 2 digit int values
and Im using c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want a regex like this

```
^(?:\d{1,2})?(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

here the non capturing group `(?:\d{1,2})` will check for values between `0 - 99`.
this has been made optional with `?` because values like `.12` , `.2` are permitted.

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/oW7rF4

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a check like this:

```
String string = "1.23";

if( 
  string.match(/^\d+$/) || // for "123", "456"
  string.match(/^\d+\.\d{1,2}$/) || // for "123.45", "4.5"
  string.match(/^\.\d{1,2}$/) )  // for ".45", ".8"
    // do something
else 
     // do something else
```

Note: This is a pseudo-code (or whatever you call it), you can convert it to your language.

Answer (score 0):

```
(^\d{1,2}$)|(^\d{0,2}[.]\d{1,2}$)
```

`(^\d{1,2}$)` is for INT 
[0 , 1 , 12 , 99]  

`(^\d{0,2}[.]\d{1,2}$)` is for FLOAT  
[.1 , .12 , 1.2 , 1.23 , 12.3 , 12.34 , .99 , 99.99]